# why is the sum = add() not working when is already defined?

Tags: python

I am new to python and my professor keeps posting this problem for the class to answer:

```
 x = 2 
 y = 3
 sum = add( x, y)
 print(sum)
 def add (num1 = 0, num2 = 0):
 total = num1 + num2
 return total
```

edit:

I figure it out by placing the sum = add( x, y) after the add() was defined. here is the correct code?

```
x = 2
y = 3

def add (x, y):
    total = x + y
    return total

sum = add( x, y)
print(sum)
```

Comment: (1) Show your own effort to understand it first. (2) Indentation of shown code is incorrect. The `*` at beginning and `**` at the end is incorrect.

Comment: Find a new teacher!

Comment: As a additional tip, try to run the code line by line in the interpreter to identify the errors

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are categorically too broad to be on-topic. Try to extract a specific thing you don't understand, try to do your own research, and then ask a narrow, specific question about that one thing.

Comment: are you sure , he was writting in python and It's not in C?

Comment: Your question cannot be answered since the code you provided is not valid Python.  Please be absolutely exact about all the details, including punctuation and indentation.  Every character matters in programming, and "close" is never good enough.

Comment: yeah sorry guys new here and didn't know how to post code :/ but the code posted above seems to do the trick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you correctly identified, this code is calling the function add before it's defined.
Furthermore, the astrix in front of the first variable is out of place - that should make a list out of otherwise unassigned variables.
The double astrix on the return line is also out of place.

The question of "What is the code trying to do?" Is poorly phrased, but I'd wager that the answer your professor is looking for is "The code is trying to print the sum of the two given variables to the console."

Comment: I'm sorry I should have provided more information and I was having trouble posting the code and somehow I added the *s lol, yeah UoPeople style of teaching is weird but is cheap, I am supplementing my learning with Automate the Boring Stuff with Python Programming in udemy.